# Are there alternatives to using "fix available via npm audit fix --force"?

Tags: file, terminal, operands, npm-audit, npm-vulnerabilities

I downloaded a file, still trying to remember the name of it ( I will update, looking for it currently ).

I never finished installing it because I seen a message about vulnerabilities and a bunch of critical ones. I immediately reverted what I had installed and deleted these downloads to the best of my ability, and from what I can tell this problem is caused from trying to download an older version, that had previously fixed "breaking changes" with an update.

*I know I'm probably saying that wrong so feel free to correct me and offer the correct explanation*

###### I then ran `npm audit fix` and deleted several of the problematic files manually, and fixed some of some but not all of theses vulnerabilities.

---

##### The terminal output ends with:

```
65 vulnerabilities (7 low, 10 moderate, 47 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

I found that it's generally not advised to use the the `--force` operand if you aren't absolutely confident in what you're doing ( As I am not ) so I'm hesitant to do this. Is there a different way of fixing this issue without subsequently having to install the files with `npm audit fix --force`?

1.) I reverted what I installed and deleted the downloads.

2.) I ran `npm audit fix`.

3.) I manually deleted several of the problematic files.